# correlation between different matrices R

Tags: r, correlation

I´m trying to create a correlation (with p values) between two different matrices (operational taxonomic units versus environmental paramenters) in R

The first table is this

biotic1  biotic2
T1 1.540184 3.080025
T2 1.354927 5.012977
T3 1.449712 4.715981
T4 1.146659 2.442083
X1 1.705184 3.881878
X2 1.182721 3.014836
X3 1.536956 2.636719
X4 1.808025 4.434525
A1 1.132737 2.135737
A2 1.506048 3.114281
A3 1.285308 4.363828
A4 3.008994 7.290423

and the second table

OTU1 OTU2 OTU3 OTU4 OTU5 OTU6 OTU7 OTU8
T1  109   80  175   14   71   46   61   39
T2  102   48   26    8   23    5   35   10
T3   26   19   61    3   68   13   10   29
T4  143   56    9   11   16   13   49   24
X1   70   36   20   15   39    9   26   12
X2   39   33   12   32   15    2   11    3
X3   43   17    2   14    8    2    7    2
X4  160   60    8   26   25    7    9   15
A1   90   73   41   15   22   23   33    7
A2  344  109   18   28   22   13   93   16
A3   65   16   15    9    5   10   18    6
A4  141  140    6   86   18    3   43    4

I have already tried cor() and corr.test() but it only seens to correlate values from the first table

Any suggestion?

Thank you very much

F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me what result you are expecting.. However if you want to perform a simple correlation test, you must have your matrices in a vector format. You can try something like:

```
cor(c(as.matrix(your_matrix1)), c(as.matrix(your_matrix2)))
```

or

```
cor.test(c(as.matrix(your_matrix1)), c(as.matrix(your_matrix2)))
```

and see if one of these options meets your expectations.

However it makes more sense to me to explore your datasets with a canonical correlation analysis. Using base R you can use:

```
cancor(matrix1, matrix2)
```

you can also use some packages that have a set of tools to interpret the results (e.g. `library(CCA)`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer G. Cocca, I want to correlate each individual OTU with environmental parameters.